# Why can't I flip the bits of a 32 bit unsigned int by bitwise ORing it with 0?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I was trying to solve a problem that required me to flip the bits of a 32 bit unsigned int that is inputted and print it.

I first trying solving it by doing something like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
// EDIT System.out.println(~scanner.nextLong() | 0);
System.out.println(~scanner.nextLong() | 0x00000000L);
```

But that didn't produce the right answer.

Then, I was able to solve it with:

```
System.out.println(~scanner.nextLong() & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
```

Can someone explain to me why my first attempt didn't work?

EDIT: clarified the code a bit.

EDIT2: Here is the problem, for those who are wondering: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/flipping-bits

EDIT3: Oh man. I really didn't think this through. '~'ing the long with only the lower 32 bits with values would result in a negative long due to the upper 32 bits of the long all flipping from 0 to 1, and ORing that long with 0 does nothing, while ANDing that long with 32 1 bits clears the upper 32 bits of that long, leaving the long with just the lower 32 bits flipped.

Comment: A bitwise OR with zero doesn't change anything. Do you mean XOR (`^`)?

Comment: @ChrisMartin, an XOR with zero also doesn't change anything.

Comment: In Java there's no such thing as a "32 bit unsigned int".  And ORing an int with zero will always be a no-op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the part that is confusing you is that `& 0xFFFFFFFFL` is one way to treat an `int` as unsigned and represent it as a signed `long`.  `| 0` does nothing.  You could also use, as of Java 8, [`Integer.toUnsignedString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toUnsignedString-int-) to convert an `int` into a `String` representation of the unsigned 32-bit value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you explain why I couldn't get the right answer by ORing the long with 0x00000000L, yet ANDing the long with 0xFFFFFFFFL works?

Comment: ORing with 0 results in the same value

Comment: Note that `0xFFFFFFFFL` is _not_ all 1 bits.  That would be `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL`.  (Longs are _long._)

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand now. Sorry my question was so confusing. What the problem wanted me to print was an unsigned 32 bit representation of a flipped signed 32 bit int. I know that Java doesn't have unsigned 32 bit ints, thus, I scanned in the value as a long. I incorrectly assumed that long was unsigned and that 0xFFFFFFFFL was 1s in all 64 bits instead of just the lower 32 bits. The reason I was getting the wrong output by ORing the flipped long with 0, is because long is signed, thus I was printing out a signed number and not the unsigned number I wanted. Thank you for your help!

Comment: with Java8 unsigned functions, only int is needed, no need to use long anymore